# Cypher: aggregates and individual selections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like a single query to find the minimum and maximum values for a property on an edge along with the value for an edge connecting to a given node.

Consider this sample database:

[image: Simple graph database]

We have a `Game` node (shown in red) and three `Person` nodes (shown in blue). Both `Game` and `Person` nodes have a `name` property, for this example lets assume the names are unique. `Person` and `Game` nodes are connected via `BEST_SCORE` edges that have a `score` property on them, each person can only have one edge connecting them to a game.

So far I have come up with this:

```
MATCH (g:Game)<-[s:BEST_SCORE]-(p:Person)
WHERE g.name='Pacman'
WITH MAX(s.score) AS max, MIN(s.score) AS min
MATCH (g:Game)<-[s:BEST_SCORE]-(p:Person) WHERE g.name='Pacman' AND p.name='Tom'
RETURN min, max, s.score
```

Giving these results:

[image: Cypher results]

These are exactly the results I want but I cannot help but think there must be a nicer way to do it? I feel there must be a better way than matching the `Game` node and its connections to `Person` nodes twice, once for the aggregates and once for the individual score? Maybe this is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for efficiency, rather than calculate the `min` and `max` every time you want to return a players score, you could re-calc the aggregates periodically and store them on the **Game** node. After a while the min and max will stop changing very often.

```
MATCH (g:Game {name:'Pacman'} )<-[s:BEST_SCORE]-(p:Person)
WITH MAX(s.score) as max_score, MIN(s.score) as min_score, g
SET g.max_score = max_score, g.min_score = min_score
```

Then you can just grab them when you are looking for a player's score.

```
MATCH (g:Game)<-[s:BEST_SCORE]-(p:Person) 
WHERE g.name='Pacman' 
AND p.name='Tom'
RETURN g.min_score, g.max_score, s.score
```

Comment: Nice idea. I actually ended up using a sort of variation on this. I'm not keen on storing what is effectively duplicated data and having to maintain it but in my case this query was performed as part of a script. I found the min and max once and stored their values in the script, looking up the scores for each individual person as and when they were needed without recalculating min and max. I realise this won't universally solve the problem but it worked for me. I'm still intrigued to see if it can be done in a single succinct query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, kudos for a detailed question, +1 !

You can pipe a collect of the relationships along with min, max and then UNWIND this collection :

```
MATCH (a:Game { name:'Pacman' })<-[r:BEST_SCORE]-(person)
WITH collect(r) AS rels, max(r.score) AS max, min(r.score) AS min 
UNWIND rels AS r
RETURN r.score AS score, min, max


score   min max
12.5    5   23.2
23.2    5   23.2
5       5   23.2
```

Comment: Thanks. That solution sort of half works, can it be modified such that it only gives me one row for a given person (but the max and the min still for the whole collection)? Adding `WHERE person.name='Tom'` will exclude other values from the min and max.